# Does HTTPS make POST data encrypted?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, https

I am new to the world of programming and I have learnt enough about basic CRUD-type web applications using HTML-AJAX-PHP-MySQL. I have been learning to code as a hobby and as a result have only been using a WAMP/XAMP setup (localhost). I now want to venture into using a VPS and learning to set it up and eventually open up a new project for public use.

I notice that whenever I send form data to my PHP file using AJAX or even a regular POST, if I open the Chrome debugger, and go to "Network", I can see the data being sent, and also to which backend PHP file it is sending the data to.

If a user can see this, can they intercept this data, modify it, and send it to the same backend PHP file? If they create their own simple HTML page and send the POST data to my PHP backend file, will it work?

If so, how can I avoid this? I have been reading up on using HTTPS but I am still confused. Would using HTTPS mean I would have to alter my code in any way?

Comment: The request / response is encrypted for transit. It's decrypted on either side.

Comment: Is all this done automatically or would I need to alter my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The browser is obviously going to know what data it is sending, and it is going to show it in the debugger. HTTPS encrypts that data in transit and the remote server will decrypt it upon receipt; i.e. it protects against any 3rd parties in the middle being able to read or manipulate the data.

This may come as a shock to you (or perhaps not), but communication with your server happens exclusively over HTTP(S). That is a simple text protocol. Anyone can send arbitrary HTTP requests to your server at any time from anywhere. HTTPS encrypted or not. If you're concerned about somebody manipulating the data being sent through the browsers debugger tools… your concerns are entirely misdirected. There are many simpler ways to send any arbitrary crafted HTTP request to your server without even going to your site.

Your server can only rely on the data it receives and must strictly validate the given data on its own merits. Trying to lock down the client side in any way is futile.

Comment: Thanks. Say I want to delete a user from the DB, in the POST data I send the username (u:20), then my MySQL query is `DELETE FROM WHERE id=?` (paremeterized query). Can Someone then just send a random userid to the backend? I can't use SESSIONS here because the page is one where the administrator is deleting users.

Comment: Yup, anyone can delete anyone then. You *need* some form of authentication there, ***especially for all-powerful admin pages***. Sessions are a typical way to do that. Why isn't that possible for an admin?

Comment: I am selecting the user to delete from a `<select>` input and then the user's id is sent via POST. If I get my users with a `SELECT * FROM USERS`, how and where can I use Sessions? When the admin logs in, it stores his/her's userid in Session, so I am not sure how to then reference another user's id using Sessions.

Comment: You use the session to ensure that an admin is logged in, and you *verify* that an admin is logged in when someone's trying to delete someone. You don't need to store the user id to delete in the session, that makes little sense here. Sounds like you're already doing the correct thing.

Comment: I see! So I can do a basic `IF` statement like  (pseudocode) `IF logged in user's level is= "1" THEN { My MySQL query - prepare-> etc etc} ` ?

Comment: Rather something like `if logged in level != 1 then respond with HTTP error 403 Forbidden and abort`, but yes…

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate your time and patience in answering my question. I have a better understanding of it all now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

This is even simpler than that.
Whether you are using GET or POST to transmit parameters, the HTTP request is sent to your server by the user's client, whether it's a web browser, telnet or anything else. The user can know what these POST parameters are simply because it's the user who sends them - regardless of the user's personal involvement in the process.

You are taking the problem from the wrong end.
One of the most important rules of programming is :
**Never trust user entries is a basic rule of programming !** Users can and **will** make mistakes, and some of them **will** try to damage you or steal from you.
*Welcome into the club.*

Therefore, you must not allow your code to perform any operation that could damage you in any way if the POST or GET parameters you receive aren't what you expect, be it by mistake or from malicious intents. If your code, by the way it's designed, renders you vulnerable to harm simply by sending specific POST values to one of your pages, then your design is at fault and you should redo it taking that problematic into account.

That problematic being a major issue while designing programs, you will find plenty of documentation, tutorials and tips regarding how to prevent your code to turn against you.

Don't worry, that's not **that** hard to handle, and the fact that you came up with that concern by yourself show how good you are at figuring things out and how commited you are to produce good code, there is no reason why you should fail.

Feel free to post another question if you are stuck regarding a particular matter while taking on your security update.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was first inserting the data directly into the DB, then I read up on SQL injection and learnt how to use parameterized queries. Here, I check that the data is the type that I expect, then add it to the DB. Is there anything else I should be doing ?

Comment: @Bruno You have to automatically escape any character that might be included in the parameters in order to hijack your SQL query from the inside, or convert them to integers if that's what you expect (simpler then). But the best practice currently is to use parameterized queries (with PDO, ideally) since the escaping is included on the fly.

Comment: I am currently doing that, as well as using parameterized queries. Please see my comment on `deceze` 's answer.

Comment: I bet `deceze` is fairly able to guide you on this ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS encrypts in-transit, so won't address this issue.

You cannot trust anything client-side. Any data sent via a webform can be set to whatever the client wants. They don't even have to intercept it. They can just modify the HTML on the page.

There is no way around this. You can, and should, do client side validation. But, since this is typically just JavaScript, it can be modified/disabled.

Therefore, you must validate all data server side when it is received. Digits should be digits, strip any backslashes or invalid special characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone can send whatever they want to your application. HTTPS just means that they can't see and manipulate what others send to your application. But you always have to work under the assumption that what is sent to your application as POST, GET, COOKIE or whatever is evil.

Answer (score 0):

In HTTPS, the TLS channel is established before and HTTP data is transfered so, from that point of view, there is no difference between GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is encrypted but that is only supposed to protects against mitm attacks.

your php backend has no idea where the data it receives comes from which is why you have to assume any data it receives comes straight from a hacker.

Since you can't protect against unsavoury data being sent you have to ensure that you handle all data received safely. Some steps to take involve ensuring that any files uploaded can't be executed (i.e. if someone uploads a php file instead of an image), ensuring that data received never directly interacts with the database (i.e. https://xkcd.com/327/), & ensuring you don't trust someone just because they say they are logged in as a user.

To protect further do some research into whatever you are doing with the received post data and look up the best practices for whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to verify in the backend PHP file where the data came from?

Comment: @Bruno There are a couple of ways e.g. the IP address however the sender  can lie about that.

Comment: @Bruno You can send a token along with the form then check that the right token is returned with the post data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if I am sending said token along with the form, then  the token data is also visible so can't an unwanted person just also send that token too?

Comment: The idea is to generate a new token for each form which can only be used once and expires after a given amount of time. You could use a PHP session instead of a token. Any way you do it it's still possible for the person recieving the cookie/token to send whatever data they want.

Comment: @Peter The sender can't typically lie about their IP address in a TCP/IP connection.

Comment: @deceze that's true, i am dumb. It's still not a particularly secure way to validate a user.