# Is it possible to manupulate the front end JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to send an AJAX request to the server only if the length of the string is less than 200 and greater than 5.

And checking the rules on client end with `if` statement:

```
if (textLen < 200 && textLen > 5) {
    // send ajax
}
```

Is it possible for any user to manipulate the front-end script like increasing the character length?

If YES, How? And if NO, Is it best practice to validate data on the client end?

Provided that the server restricts post request from all the external source other than `mydomain.com`

Comment: Yes, users can do anything they want to your front end code.  Clientside validation is just for convenience; anything secure has to be done on the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484708/476

Comment: @deceze HTTPS is completely out of context I guess. OP asking about changing variable values in browser ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'm mostly referring to the second and third paragraphs in that answer.

Comment: You can try it out yourself. Open a console on your own webpage and copy  > paste the ajax code from inside the `if` statement. It will get executed! That means that any other user could also do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is easily possible to change the variable value on client side. Just don't rely on client side validations. 
Do not assume the validation successfully done at client side is 100% perfect. Always trust/depend on your server side validations. That's the best.

Comment: Liked your discussion on another answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes anyone can change the client side code and remove the validation checks. So always handle the validation on server side as well.

Comment: How could one **remove** the validation checks?

Comment: @BenM Open the debugger, delete the lines.

Comment: @BenM `if(valid) {// reach server.}`. Through debugger tools, `valid =true`.

Comment: @deceze In an external JS file?

Comment: @BenM if jQuery is loaded: `$('#ElementId').rules('remove');`

Comment: @BenM Yup. Doesn't matter where that code comes from. If it's running in the browser, you can manipulate it using the browser's debugger tools. But really, this is already too detailed a focus. You don't need to do any of this in the browser. Just use any arbitrary tool that can send HTTP requests and send any garbage to the server you want; you don't even need to bother opening the site or executing any Javascript.

Comment: @deceze Not to spam the thread here (I'm not the OP), but could you expand on how an attacker can modify the content of an external JS file loaded from the server? It's possible to bypass the validation easily using dev tools, but the file contents itself surely cannot be modified once delivered?

Comment: @BenM Even it is loaded from an external source, still executes in browser and you can put break on any line you wanted. Thus you got a chance to update the variables of the script through console.

Comment: @BenM Again, if I'm an attacker trying to attack your server, I'm not going to bother with any of this; I'm just going to send straight HTTP requests to your server using curl or whatever. – The only time I'd bother with manipulating Javascript is if I'm a [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and I'm injecting malicious Javascript into the page your browser is downloading from OP's server.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes exactly. But that's distinctly very different from the sweeping statement made in this answer that anyone can *change* client-side code. That's not true; an attacker can remove validation from inline or tag-based JS, but they'd have to *bypass* if the validation was in an external file. There's a subtle difference, and maybe I'm splitting hairs here ;)

Comment: @BenM Not sure I'm seeing the difference. *Anyone* can be the user, by poking around the debugger. Or it can be a MitM, straight up manipulating JS on the fly/serving an alternative file. Or it can be the user running a local proxy, essentially MitM'ing themselves.

Comment: @deceze The difference is thus: the answer states anyone can change the client-side code and *remove* the validation. That's not true if the JS is an external file loaded from the server (you cannot modify the content of an external JS script). The only option is to *bypass* the validation. If the script code appears inside a `<script>` tag, then we may use dev tools to modify it. It's a subtle difference, and entirely academic as you've already pointed out.

Comment: @BenM I have no idea why you think the Javascript being in an "external file" makes any sort of difference. It does not.

Comment: @deceze Is this possible if the JS is in an 'external file'? *Open the debugger, delete the lines.*

Comment: @BenM Yes. If your browser's debugger allows any sort of on-the-fly manipulation at all, it allows it equally to all Javascript regardless of where it comes from.

Comment: @deceze Consider this: `<script src="assets/js/validate.js"></script>`. How can I open up dev tools and delete lines from this file as you've said in response to my very first comment? I am not talking about manipulating vars or tampering with responses, simply about how it's possible to entirely remove logic from a file...

Comment: @BenM Of course this isn't going to affect the actual file on the server, if that's what you're driving at. But if so, nobody ever talked about that.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The point is @BenM, JavaScript files are served to the client who sent a GET request to the server in the first place. They're on the local machine of that client. They can do whatever they like with the file. No, it won't change the file source, but the script is executed locally anyway so they can edit out every validation conditional you put in and send Ajax requests to your server anyway. Or they could just use the address you probably hardcoded in there and send them with their own script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to change any code that you receive from a server to display a webpage. Press "`F12`" on your keyboard and start modifying.

About the code you put in you're question, I'm assuming you wish to client-side check the if the length of a string fits between a minimum and maximum length. The names suggest that the variables contain the text, if so, modify the code to:

```
if (textLen.length < 200 && textLen.length > 5) {
    // send ajax
}
```

To modify code on the client, so before it gets to the server, open your browsers' development tools (F12 for most browsers). Double click what you wish to change.

However, to make sure that stuff does not get accepted on the server you should ALWAYS validate everything server-side. So the requirements for a maximum string length of 200 and minimum length of 5 should also be checked by the server, before continuing doing anything with it. This, of course, next to other checks, such as checking for any unwanted code, white-space, etc.